# wrong constant name Comments.controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I run `rails s` , I get the following error:

> `/Users/cs/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-1.4.3/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:586:in 'const_defined?': wrong constant name Comments.controller (NameError)`

How can I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably one controller's class is named `Comments.controller`. It should be `CommentsController`. Find `Comments.controller` in project and change it to `CommentsController`

Comment: The problem is not the class definition. Its a lookup error.